# preg_match_all suddenly ceased to find occurrences in text

Tags: php, fedora, preg-match-all, pcre

I have code that find occurences in email body by using preg_match_all. Something like this:

```
$sHrefPattern = "<(a|area)\s*.*(unsubscribe_url\s*=\s*?)([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)";
if (preg_match_all("/$sHrefPattern/siU", $sHtmlBody, $aMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    // do smth ...
}
```

and content like this (can contains russian text occurences):

```
... <td align="left" colspan="3" height="22" valign="center">
    <a style="font-size: 8pt; color: #666; padding-left: 13px; font-family: arial;" unsubscribe_url="http://ourcliensite.org/unsubscribe.html">
        Unsubscribe
    </a> |
    <a href="http://ourservice.com/linkswrap?did=819&sid=1&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ourclinetsite.org&dig=7bef6d9ed912392a689bdb9bb6cc581d" style="font-size: 8pt; color: #666; padding-left: 13px; font-family: arial;">
        Advertisement in emails
    </a>
</td> ...
```

For a long time this code has worked fine. But one fine day this code stopped working correctly. I think it correlates to some package installations, but I don't know which package has been installed. Server on which this code is working has being shared access in our team. Any ideas?

```
uname -a
Linux ourhost 2.6.32-042stab076.8 #1 SMP Tue May 14 20:38:14 MSK 2013 i686 i686 i386    GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Maybe it's a sign to move on an HTML parser ? It **must** be fate :o

Comment: Oh no, please. It is not pure html. It is html email body formed by PHPMailer.

Comment: Do you get any errors ? Also check out [preg_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php).

Comment: preg_last_error returns nothing.

Comment: Ok, try just something simple `preg_match_all('#foo#', 'foo bar foo bar too foo', $m); print_r($m);`. If this returns 3 foo, then it means the data you're "expecting" has changed.

Comment: Yes, it is. 'foo' is printed 3 times. I forgot, my html contains russian text occurrences.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Change the `U` (uppercase) modifier to `u` (lowercase). `U` will make your match ungreedy and `u` will treat your pattern strings as UTF-8. In this case you need `u` (lowercase).

Answer (score 1):

Check the character set involved. I don't know *anything* about recent changes to php in this respect, but do your regexps also contain russian? Are you using an 8-bit Cyrillic character set, or UTF-8? Is it explicitly set or detected by PHP? Perhaps your code just ignores the issue of coding, and some default changed somewhere. I'd suggest debugging it as if it's new code. Find a regexp that fails, find a small input it fails on, and try to determine its encoding.

Regexps can take the `u` modifier to deal with unicode intelligently, so I'd try that first in case it automagically fixes everything.

Answer (score 1):

I think evil people have edited your pattern when you are asleep, fortunately, i suggest you to test this pattern to replace the old:

```
$sHrefPattern = "<a(?>rea)?\b(?>[^u]++|u++(?!nsubscribe_url\b))+"
               ."unsubscribe_url\s*+=\s*+[\"']?+\K[^\"'\s]++";
preg_match_all("/$sHrefPattern/iu", $sHtmlBody, $aMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($aMatches);
```

It is optimised for quick fail, note the new flags too, and now the result is the whole pattern (capture groups are not needed), (ie group 0).